# How to open same website post urls in WebView app directly?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I am created a WebView app based on a Url like  website.some, i am shared a post link like website.some/post_name/ to my frnds when they open that link through my webview app is not opens post page link directly, it opens only my website main page link (wesite.some).i want this action like Snapdeal or flipkart directly open page in my webview app. please help me.

**Main Activity like this**

```cs
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setSavePassword(true);
    settings.setSaveFormData(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://website.some/");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MywebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private class MywebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("website.some/")){
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("please wait...");
        pd.setMessage("Page is loading..");
        pd.show();
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        pd.dismiss();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode){
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(wv.canGoBack()){
                    wv.goBack();
                }
                else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("website.some")){
             view.loadUrl(url); //optional
             return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldOverrideUrlLoading method called when url inside onPageFinished get changed.

```
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String url) 
        {
                 if (url.contains("websiteLink"))
                 view.loadUrl(url); 

             return false;
        }
```